# How to setup a guacamole on a windows machine?

Tags: remote-access, rdp, guacamole

From official website of gaucamole i.e. (http://guacamole.incubator.apache.org)-

> Apache Guacamole is a clientless remote desktop gateway. It supports
>   standard protocols like VNC, RDP, and SSH.
>
> We call it clientless because no plugins or client software are
>   required.
>
> Thanks to HTML5, once Guacamole is installed on a server, all you need
>   to access your desktops is a web browser.

Can I setup guacamole on windows server 2012. If yes how ?

Comment: Myrtille might be a good alternative for windows: https://cedrozor.github.io/myrtille/  "...it works like comparable solutions (Guacamole or FreeRDP-WebConnect, to name a few), but is more specifically intended for Windows as it uses IIS and the .NET (C#) framework."

Answer (score 10):

It should be possible to run the Guacamole Docker container in the Docker Toolbox under Windows Server 2012.
This reduces the overhead compared to a full blown VM like suggested by Bram.

Answer (score 4):

The anwser is no, the manual is made for linux distro (since the guacd daemon is written for Linux).. So i would install it on Ubuntu in vmware on the Windows server. That way it is possible.